# Opening multiple netcdf files with same dimensions and data variables in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

There are two netCDF files that have 3 dimensions ('lon', 'lat', 'time'). The names and values of dimensions are equal in two files. These files have 12 data variables that the name of data variables are same but the values are different. I want to open this big files with `open_mfdataset` in `xarray` that the all data variables in both files read, but the result returns only 12 data variables of one of files. What is the correct setting in `open_mfdataset` command?

```
xdf = xr.open_mfdataset(file_path + '*.nc', concat_dim='time')
```

Comment: Have you tried open each file separately? What do you need to do with these two files? As far as I understood, you cannot concatenate the two files because their dimensions are the same.

Comment: Hi iurysimoes-sousa, I want to have a single dataset that with 3 dimensions ('lon', 'lat', 'time') and all of data variables from input files. I tried to change the name of data variables in one input file, but because of file size (big file), it did not work.

Comment: You can try opening each file separately and using `xr.merge`. But you definitely need different variable names. If both files are with the same dimensions and variable names, you can also use `xr.concat` to concatenate into a new dimension setting up `dim='<name>'`.